# $x\langle S\rangle x^{-1}=\langle S\rangle$ proof from group theory notes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is lemma 1.13 of [these](http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math101aF07/Math101aF2007.htm) lecture notes. The group theory text. But I don't see it is so obvious.

[image]

Comment: Please don't leave your question in the title alone. And please provide more details to your question (there is no question right now, just a statement).

Comment: Please, include a direct link or picture of what you want, it is impossible to find your lemma in that list.

Comment: Please make your question self-contained. The fact you are after is not true in general, although presumably it is true in the specific context you are in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course the teacher means $x\langle S\rangle x^{-1}=\langle xS x^{-1}\rangle$.